# is there a way to perform get and set atomically in redis?

Tags: redis, atomic, jedis

I'm using jedis, and wish to get the result of a key and modify it and then store it back,

```
String dataToModify = jedis.get(parent_id);
//some modify  eg:  
modifiedData = dataToModify + "modify";
jedis.set(parent_id, modifiedData);
```

but I then realized that if someone else modified data in key `parent_id`, between this `get` and `set`, there will be collision. the `watch-multi-exec` does not work since I need to get the value of key `parent_id` during the transaction. Is there any other way to do this atomically? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure regarding the exact jedis syntax, but Redis' WATCH/MULTI/EXEC will let you do that (I.e. run the get/set flow atomically). Alternatively, if you implement your workflow in a server-side Lua script, that would also guarantee atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the date in epoch (also known as [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) value, this way you can treat your date as a number and use [INCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/incrby) command e.g.:
`jedis.incrby(parent_id, modify);`